# How variables with different values are referenced?

Tags: java

I am working through some exercises and was wondering if someone could explain how `int a` and `a = 15` are referenced separately?

```
public class SwapVariables {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a, b; 
    a = 15;
    b = 27;
    System.out.println("Before swap: a = "+a+" b = "+b);
    a = a + b;
    b = a - b;
    a = a - b;
    System.out.println("After swap: a = "+a+" b = "+b);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you clarify, that what you want to ask? do want to know that how this swap works or do you want to know about how variable value reference works.

Comment: both, although I've not come across 'variable value reference' a quick google search indicates the order in which values are assign to variables is probably the basis of what i'm trying to understand...

Comment: It might also help to explain what you want the code to do, because the 'swap' in the System.outs implies that you're trying to swap the values of a and b, but there's no swapping of values in your code, you're just performing adds and subtracts? I'm guessing you're looking to understand how references work and how parameter passing semantics work in Java, but your question and the example code so far don't seem to be on the same page (probably not helping with the understanding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good answer by Elliot, but to get a better understanding how it works. At the beginning you are declaring two variables a and b. Those are just references in memory in a zone that is 4 bytes each in size (int in java is 32 bits). In the second line you are saying go to those 4 bytes which i "called" them a and give them the name "a" and make their value 15. So in memory you are performing a write process. Same thing for b. Next you are performing a read at the beginning and after that a write. You are saying go to the "a" point in memory and get the value, go to the "b" point in memory and get the value and perform addition which is 42. Take the result and go write it in the "a" point in memory. Now "a" has a new value and the old value is changed. Unless a change in that memory zone happens the value of a will be 42. The same logic is applied in the all the subsequent rows. Hope it helps for a better understanding!

Answer (score 1):

They are not "referenced", because they are primitive value types.

```
a = 15 + 27 = 42
b = 42 - 27 = 15
a = 42 - 15 = 27
```

**tl;dr** Math.

Comment: Thanks that helps me understand what I was trying to ask better.  Which value of 'a' is the second System.out.println statement referencing/calling.  I'm assuming it's the last definition of a (a = a-b), and the a-b in this formula is the preceding definition of a and b...correct?

Comment: This is **exactly** what the middle section of your code does (with the values filled in). Hence the value of `a` is **27** when you print it the second time.